# How to split a string with "." separator in C

Tags: c

I want to split a string with "." separator in C. For example, I have a string like this "studentdetails.txt". Now I want to result like this "studentdetails" and "txt". Please give me any idea to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You may know about  [strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/strtok.html) in C.

Ex.

```
char str[] = "studentdetails.txt";
char delims[] = ".";
char *result = NULL;
result = strtok( str, delims );
while( result != NULL ) {
    printf( "%s\n", result );
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a strtok() function.

```
char str[] ="This is a sample string, just testing.";
char *p;

printf ("Split \"%s\" in tokens:\n", str);

p = strtok (str," ");

while (p != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n", p);
    p = strtok (NULL, " ,");
}
return 0;
```

I have used a space... just use "." instead

Comment: better use `strtok_r()` for safety (and readability) reasons.

Comment: The word is you rather then u. If it's worth writing an answer then it's worth using real words rather than text speak.

Comment: The word is "than" and not "then" in your first sentence. If it's worth writing a comment, then its worth using proper grammar than not using one.

sorry couldn't help myself. Cheers. :)